# Post-Build event msbuild. Rename file at end of successful build

Tags: visual-studio, file, msbuild, version, rename

I don't know MSbuild scripting and don't have time to learn it right now. I need a method at the end of successful build to rename a dacpac file to include the version that is currently being built.

Example: (TfsDropLocation)\filename.dapac to (TfsDropLocation\filename.1.0.0.0.dacpac)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm. This was a really big help. Again thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

The answer is yes. If you don't mind editing the Visual Studio project file, then there is a simple solution that allows you to use a macro which looks like this:`@(VersionNumber)`:

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag, place below scripts:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
     $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
     PostBuildMacros;
   </PostBuildEventDependsOn>    
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <ItemGroup>
    <VersionNumber Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)')"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Now as promised, the assembly version is available to your post build event with this macro. So you add rename the file name by copy task in the post-build event with below command line:

```
copy /Y  "(TfsDropLocation)\filename.dapac" "(TfsDropLocation)\filename.@(VersionNumber).dapac"
```

If you do not want to keep the previous `filename.dapac`, you can add a `del` command in the post-build event:

```
del "(TfsDropLocation)\filename.dapac"
```

Note: Do not ignore double quotation marks in the post-build event command line.

Then you can check you output and windows explorer, I used the file dll to test, you can check my test result:

[image]

[image]